# Convergence of an integral under a condition

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Let $F:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty F(x)e^{-x}dx<\infty.
\end{align}

Is it true that

$$\int_0^\infty F(x)e^{-x}xdx<\infty?$$

Comment: $F(x) = e^x /(1 + x^2)$.

Answer (score 2):

You can manipulate $F(x)$ to your heart's desire, so your question is equivalent to the following: given that $\int_0^\infty f(x) dx < \infty$, do we always have $\int_0^\infty xf(x)dx < \infty$?

The answer is obviously no, can you pick some $f(x) = 1/(x-1)^k$ for example for the right value of $k$?